# update user's data Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hi i'm trying to update some of user's data **username** and **password**

[image]

my code below checks if email of current user are exists or not if exists i want to update the old informations with new informations, but my code doesn't work ,it adds me a new user instead of updating user data

```
update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                updateUser();
            }
        });


private void updateUser() {
        final DatabaseReference mUser = mDatabase.child("users").child("id");
        mUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    String emailUser = user.getEmail();
                    if (email.equals(emailUser)) {
                        user.setUsername(name.getText().toString());
                        user.setPassword(newpassword.getText().toString());
                        user.setImageBase64(imageBase64);
                        mUser.setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Votre compte a été modifé!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please read this post on [storing passwords in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks so much for your comment but my app released for study project i don't need to crypte password or something like this

Comment: make sure you are passing that `pushId`.

Comment: should look something like this as Frank mentioned. `updateUser('-L7vu-6HqcC_YJW40fYa')`.

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi please see my new update code

Comment: I would suggest to use [Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) of firebase to retrieve such data.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `updateUser("id");`. You probably want to call it as `updateUser(id);`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using this line of code:

```
mUser.setValue(user)
```

It means that you are adding a new user under: `users/id`, it doesn't mean that you are updating that particular user. In order to update a value within a user object, I recommend you using a `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("password", newpassword.getText().toString());
mUser.child("-L7vu-6HqcC_YJW40fYa").updateChildren(map);
```

As you can see, I have used `updateChildren()` method instead of `setValue()` and I also have added the child that is missing from your reference.